# Remove unused dependencies from pyproject.toml

Tags: python, dependencies, pyproject.toml

Over time, more and more libraries have been added as dependencies but some are not used anymore in my code.

What's the easiest way to remove all unnecessary dependencies instead of remove each one by one and testing if my code is broken?

The most I tried is removing each dependency and testing my code is broken but that takes a while.

Comment: Remove them all and add them back in until it works.

Comment: Look up `pipreqs` and `pigar`.

Answer (score 1):

[deptry](https://fpgmaas.github.io/deptry/) doesn't actually remove them, but produces a nice report to guide you to what needs removing.